# MySQL 5.1.* Strange trigger replication behavior

Tags: mysql, triggers, replication

I have a MySQL master-slave configuration.

On both servers I have two tables: `table1` and `table2`

I also have the following trigger on both servers:

```
  Trigger: test_trigger
    Event: UPDATE
    Table: table1
Statement: insert into table2 values(null)
   Timing: AFTER
```

The structure of `table2` is the following:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The problem is that, on `MySQL 5.1.*`, when the slave calls the trigger it adds the id that was inserted on the master and NOT the id it should insert according to its own auto_increment value.

Let's say I have the following data:

On Master:

```
SELECT * FROM table2;
Empty set (0.08 sec)
```

On Slave:

```
SELECT * FROM table2;

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*(just ignore the fact that the slave is not a complete mirror of the master)*

Given the above scenario, when I update a row from table1 on Master, the Slave stops and returns an error:

> Error 'Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query.

I don't see why the slave tries to insert a specific ID.

It's very strange that on `MySQL 5.0.*` this doesn't happen.

Comment: Are you using statement based replication?

Comment: @Vatev yes - it's statement based replication

Answer (score 0):

Switch to row-based replication if possible.

Auto increment is pretty much broken for anything but the most basic cases with statement based replication.

For any statement which generates more than one auto_increment value (via triggers, multi row inserts, etc.) only the 1-st auto_increment value will always be correct on the slave (only the 1-st is logged).

If the slave reads an auto_increment value from the log, but does not 'use' it, the value gets used for the next statement (which can be completely unrelated). This happens when the slave skips the corresponding insert statement for some reason (an ignored table/db in the configuration, a conditional insert in a proc/trigger, etc.).

I had a similar problem with an audit-log type table (a trigger inserts an event in table2 for every change to table1) along with several other auto-increment related problems.

I'm not sure this solution will fit your case but I'm going to post it just in case:

- Add a 'updated_count' field to table1. It starts at 0 (on insert) and gets incremented by 1 on every update (using BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE triggers).
- Remove table2's auto_increment and change its PK to a composite key `(table1_pk,table1_update)`. Then use table1's PK and 'updated_count' in the AFTER INSERT/UPDATE triggers for table2's PK.

Comment: The thing is that changing the way the app works right now would take too long (it's some legacy web-app; that should explain the antique MySQL version - 5.0.24)

My goal is to fix the issue with the auto_increment on the slave to ignore anything it reads from binlog and just use the next available value for that column. But it seems to be trickier that it looks like ...

Comment: You should check if row-based replication is an option. Switching between them is trivial. Otherwise you should try to find out where the wrong auto-increment value is coming from. There is probably a statement somewhere which inserts a row on the master but doesn't on the slave.